# Filter list of dictionaries with higher key value remove duplicate dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries like:

```
sel_list = [{'a': 8}, {'a': 4}, {'a': 4}, {'b': 8}, {'b': 9}]
```

I want to remove duplicate dictionaries and if more than one dictionaries have same key but different values then choose that dictionary with higher value.

Like :

```
sel_list = [{'a': 8}, {'b': 9}]
```

I have tried:

```
[i for n, i in enumerate(sel_list) if i not in sel_list[n + 1:]]
```

its results in:

```
[{'a': 8}, {'a': 4}, {'b': 8}, {'b': 9}]
```

What I can do to achieve my results?

Comment: So every dictionary contains *exactly* one key-value pair?

Comment: Is the order of the result important?

Comment: yes, every dict contains one key value pair and order is not important.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool If order is not important and you want one value per key, why are you not using a `dict` as your data structure? Why the `list`? See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can do this by constructing a *dictionary* that "folds" the values by picking the maximum each time. Like:

```
dummy = object()
maximums = {}
for subd in sel_list:
    for k, v in subd.items():
        cur = maximums.get(k, dummy)
        if cur is dummy or v > cur:
            maximums[k] = v
result = [{k: v} for k, v in maximums.items()]
```

We thus iterate over the *key-value* pairs of the dictionaries in the list, and each time update the `maximums` dictionary in case the key does not yet exists, or the current value is less.

After this iteration step, we produce a list of dictionaries with the maximum key-value pairs.

This approach works on all types that *can* be ordered (numbers, strings, etc.), and the keys should be hashable, but this assumption holds since in the list of dictionaries, the keys are already hashed.

Furthermore it works rather robust in the sense that it will ignore empty dictionaries, and will process a dictionary with multiple key-value pairs as well, by seeing these as independent key-value pairs.

You can also decide to work with `maximums` directly: a dictionary that contains all the keys in your original list, and associates these with the maximum value seen in the list.

Comment: This looks very interesting. I think I'm going to learn about some hidden gems in python. Would you please explain why do you use `object()` and not for example `None`? Wouldn't it be simpler to just do: `cur = maximums.get(k, None)` and then compare: `if cur is None or v > cur:`?

Comment: @cezar: because technically speaking, one can make objects with an order relation with `None`. If for example `None` occurs once, we might want to include it into the result list as well. By adding a dummy, we make a distinction between a `None` in the dictionary, and not found.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't think about the possibility of having `None` as value in the dict. I'll remember this, it may evenutally save my ass at some point.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I recommend `maximums.get(k, v)` and lose the `dummy`. I still think OP has the wrong data layout (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**  : I'm not sure How much ***Pythonic*** is my solution
Assuming the `dict` contain **only one** key,value pair. (ie, `{"a":2,"b":3}` is not a valid dict here)

```
sel_list = [{'a': 0}, {'a': 4}, {'a': 4}, {'b': 8}, {'b': 9}, {'d': 9}]
result_dict = {}
for item in sel_list:
    key = list(item.keys())[0]
    if key in result_dict:
        if item[key] > result_dict[key][key]:
            result_dict.update({key: item})
    else:
        result_dict.update({key: item})
result_list = [v for k, v in result_dict.items()]
print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sel_list = [{'a': 8}, {'a': 4}, {'a': 4}, {'b': 8}, {'b': 9}]

results = defaultdict(list)

for element in sel_list:
    for key, value in element.items():
        results[key].append(value)

for item_key, item_value in results.items():
    results[item_key] = max(item_value)

print(results)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': 9, 'a': 8})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via a `reduce` operation where a `dict` is your state:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain

sel_list = [{'a': 8}, {'a': 4}, {'a': 4}, {'b': 8}, {'b': 9}]

# function to aggregate max value item into a `dict`
def agg(d, kv):
    k, v = kv
    d[k] = max(d.get(k, v), v)
    return d

# concatenate all items from all `dict`s
sel_items = chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, sel_list))

# aggregate using a single `dict` which implicitly holds required semantics
result = reduce(agg, sel_items, {}) # {'a': 8, 'b': 9}  <-- better?
```

To get your output format (which is **not** favorable over `dict` IMO):

```
formatted = [dict((item, )) for item in result.items()]
```

`dict` has semantics that work in your favor. I think it is a better data structure for you.